# Proposal to split "velocity" tag into "apache-velocity" and "velocity"

Tags: support, retag-request

If you look at current questions tagged with "velocity" - 90% of them are about Apache Velocity template engine, the rest is about "a velocity".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/velocity

I think it would be a good idea to rename current velocity tag to "apache-velocity", and then extract "a velocity" questions from it. Currently there are only about 200 question, so it would be better to do it now than when there are few thousands of them.

Answer (score 2):

Rather, Apache Velocity should get the velocity tag, and regular velocities shouldn't have a tag since velocity in and of itself has nothing to do with programming.

Especially since Apache Velocity dominates the majority of that tag, it should be the sole owner.

Doesn't that sound better?

Comment: It sounds better, but people would be still constantly tagging unrelated questions with "velocity". Not having "a velocity" tag sounds a bit harsh, it could be probably legit for some questions.

Comment: I don't agree. The velocity tag should help people who are searching for velocity (the physics thing) related code.  I don't think it should be removed.

Comment: Can you provide an example question about velocity (the physics thing) where the fact that it's tagged velocity is necessary to the question? Stack Overflow is not the place to ask, "What's the equation to calculate velocity?"

Comment: I do not have an example.  Nor do I wanna search for one.  My point is just that I don't think it should be explicitly disallowed.